# drop event on ListBox occurring before collection is re-ordered

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox with a Drop event that fires when a row is moved via drag and drop.  The event fires correctly, but the observable collection which is the ListBox's item source does not reflect this change in the event.  If I fire a click event after I drop the row, I see the correct ordering.  So, I am guessing that the ordering happens AFTER the drop event is fired.

How do I correctly capture the re-ordering of this observable collection after a row is dropped?

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbox_playerContainer"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ChildObjectOC}"  
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChildObject, Mode=TwoWay}"
    dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
    dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"    
    Drop="lstbox_playerContainer_Drop">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Did you try binding-mode TwoWay for the `ItemSource`? Don't know the default for `ListBox`

Comment: The nice thing about an observable collection is that you can observe it. Register for the `CollectionChanged` event on the collection. When that fires, the collection has been updated.

Comment: Sweet.  I will try that out...

Comment: It doesn't work.  Re-ordering the collection never fires the event.